# How to select a window and or use send keys in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have very little knowledge of batch files (im a vba man, but the pc ill be using has no excel)

I want to use a batch file to select a window that is open call "AABTS - 1" once that window is selected I need to use press tab twice, then space, then enter.

This task is done hundreds of times, but i considering making a batch file to go through and do this for each one, but im looking for info.

The window name will not change, not will the commands I need to change, so it must be posisble, but im at a blank, can someone give me point please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

You can generate script to send keys to a window. Window can be referenced by title.

Comment: Ill give it a look, im not sure ill be able to install any software on the machine, which is why I was considering hand writting them, if its possible

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do it with AutoIT (which is the best option) you can do it with a VBScript. The following will do what you want, once every second, 300 times. Adjust as necessary

```
'Save as SendAABTS.vbs and double click to run
set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
For x = 1 to 300
  WshShell.AppActivate "AABTS - 1"
  WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
  WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
  WshShell.SendKeys "{SPACE}"
  WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
  wscript.sleep 1000
Next
```